# Is there a way to get all of the non-null members of a class without reflection or getters?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class that that can potentially assign values to 50+ plus variables. I don't want to write getters for all of these fields. I would rather have some way that can report which fields have had a value assigned to them and, what that value is.

I had originally made these private and, I know that reflection basically breaks private. Additionally, Securecoding.org states this about reflection:

> In particular, reflection must not be used to provide access to classes, methods, and fields unless these items are already accessible without the use of reflection. For example, the use of reflection to access or modify fields is not allowed unless those fields are already accessible and modifiable by other means, such as through getter and setter methods.

My main concern is mucking up my code by declaring dozens of instance variables(and possibly getters). Later in this project, I will have two more large sets of instance variables that need to be declared as well. I know that I can reduce the use of getters with some clever maps and enums but, that still takes parsing dozens ofnull values. Could anyone suggest another way?

Comment: *without reflection or getters?* then make all the fields public to access directly but not suggested at all. What is the issue with `getters`?

Comment: I think that your concerns smell as a bad design or wrong requirements. Class with 50+ fields?! Even larger data sets?!

Comment: @AlexR - ID3 tags have about 60 values depending on what version you're using. I don't like that at all but, I'm supporting all of the possible tags as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 1):

I know only 4 ways to access field of class

1. directly unless field is `private`
2. Using method, e.g. getter.
3. Using constructor.
4. Using reflection

The ways 1 and 4 are beyond the discussion. 
Constructor usage is not convenient here because huge number of fields.

So, methods the possibility.

It is up to you whether you want to use bean convention or for example builder pattern, but if you need this class for persistency or for serialization into XML or JSON etc you need at least getters.

Now, if you just want to validate the instance after its creation you can declare your interface `Validatable` that declares method `validate()` and call it when your object should be ready. You have to however implement and maintain this method for each class.

Alternative way is to use one of available validation frameworks. In this case you validation can be done using annotations. You should remember however that behind the scene such frameworks use reflection.

Here are some links for further reading:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/

http://java-source.net/open-source/validation

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html